# Excel to Access linked table date format issues

Tags: ms-access, excel-2010, ms-access-2010, linked-tables

i have an excel sheet linked into access which has varying data type.
I'm having an issue specifically with dates though.  In excel dates are formated as dd/mm/yyyy.  When the data reaches access is it numeric.  i.e. the number that relates to the date ...  19/07/2013 is being brought through as 41474.

I have tried to change the access table format, but as its linked the format cannot be specified on the access side of things.

Is there a way i can ensure that the date format is maintained?

Alternatively, is there a way i can manipulate the 'number' into a date format so that when reports are generated by users on the data, the report would show the date format correctly?

any advice greatfuly received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Under the covers"*, the Date\Time data type is actually double precision float.  So you can use query with functions to transform those numbers from the linked table as you wish --- to *explicit* Date/Time values or formatted strings containing the date in your preferred format..

Here's a couple of samples from the Immediate window.

```vb
? CDate(41474)
7/19/2013
```

The date was displayed in my (American) locale setting.  If you want it as a string in *"dd-mm-yyyy"* format, you can use the `Format()` function.  (It's still the same Date/Time value, but just displayed in a different format.)

```vb
? Format(CDate(41474), "dd/mm/yyyy")
19/07/2013
```

Comment: i understand that the number relates to the correctly formatted date value, but how do i then get them displayed correctly in the report.  The field is called 'Start Date'

Comment: Use a query as the report's record source.  In the query, you can transform the number as you wish.

Comment: ahh so the format is set in the query and not the report.  I will give it a try!

Comment: worked a treat!! many thanks!!  I was trying to get it to work in the report and not the query :)

Comment: Right, I revised the answer to make it clearer I was talking about a query.  You could also apply those functions to data controls in a report, but I think it's more convenient to do that in the report's record source query.